# Show that the map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$ is not a homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

$$f(a, b)=(a + b, a + 2, a − b)$$

How do I prove that this function preserves both addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: Check. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Easiest test: Does $f$ map $0$ to $0$?

Comment: Think of $(a,b)$ as a vector... a single mathematical object.  Show that, $f(a+c,b+d) \ne  f(a,b) + f(c,d).$

Comment: what is that test called @Dougm

Comment: It is the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f(0,0)=(0,2,0)$. Then 
$$
(0,2,0)=f(0,0)=f((0,0)+(0,0))=f(0,0)+f(0,0)=(0,4,0). 
$$
The contradiction shows that no linear function can map $(0,0)$ to $(0,2,0)$.

As mentioned above by Bye_World, any linear function maps $0$ to $0$.

Comment: Does this test work for testing the preservation of addition on all problems?

Comment: Yes. If $f$ is additive, then $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$, and so $f(0)=0$. In any context where you have addition an cancellation ($x+y=x$ implies $y=0$).